# How to reduce the size of Google Play Services in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, admob, google-play-services

Is there any way to reduce the size of Google Play Services? After I install Google Play Services the size of my User code size has increased to 6,7 Mb , the maximum of free edition being 128 kb so it don't let me compile ..

PS: I need just Admob from Google Play Services

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think so. All components are included when calculating app size...http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2912/xamarin-starter-edition-build-limits

Comment: @MilenPavlov http://snag.gy/DDr9s.jpg ..